# Summation in R quicker method

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I have a summation from i=1 to 10 in 10.000/1/12^t = 56.502
In R :

```
n =10
t = seq(1,n,1);t
g = rep(0,n) 
r = 0.12
for (i in t) {
   g[i] = 10000/((1+r)^t[i])
   GPV = sum(g)
}
GPV
```

Is there a quicker way other than for loop in R, in order to calculate this summation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
> n <- 10

> r <- 0.12

> sum(10000 / (1 + r)^seq(n))
[1] 56502.23
```